# what does 2n and m stands for?

Tags: algorithm, math

> Suppose we need at most m guesses for an array of length n. Then, for an array of length 2n, the first guess cuts the reasonable portion of the array down to size n, and at most m guesses finish up, giving us a total of at most m+1, plus, 1 guesses.

What is the meaning of array of length 2n and m in this statement, what does it denote? i've also seen other symbols like o(n). 
(Plus,does anyone know good reading materials to learn about these symbols)

Comment: `n` is the number of elements (length/size) of the array, as the text mentions. `2n` is `2 * n`, or twice `n`. O(n) is [big o notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), which is a way of describing asymptotic growth rates of algorithms relative to the input size. I'm voting to close as [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for the "asking for a tutorial" category.

Comment: So that's what it meant. it's all clear now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The symbols *m* and *n* don't have general definitions; rather, they're available to be used in whatever way is needed when discussing a given problem, and their problem-specific definitions generally need to be given at that time.

In your quotation, the first sentence:

> Suppose we need at most *m* guesses for an array of length *n*.

is actually the definition of *m* and *n*. If you prefer, you could read it like this:

> For any given array, we need a certain number of guesses. Let *n* be a certain length, and let *m* be the greatest number of guesses we need for any array of length *n*.

Answer (score 0):

They're not special symbols. Just generic letters... N (or X) are very common for denoting an unknown amount. M (or Y) usually refer to the next number in the problem.

M is the number of guesses, as the problem says

2N is 2 times N, or double the length of the array

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite broad. But using the context you are given, let me give you an example where this is used.

Suppose we are searching an array using Merge sort ( if you are new to merge sort read here https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merge-sort/ ).

There will be m comparisons(m guesses) to find the specified element in the array. 
When we double the number of elements in the array( in your case 2n) it will take m+1 comparisons (m+1 guesses) at most.